# Java.Lang.StackOverflowError on Finish using Xamarin

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, xamarin

I have a fragment (contained in an activity) that starts another activity from a button click event.

```
void Button_Click (object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    Activity.StartActivityForResult(typeof(ActivityB), 0);
}
```

ActivityB has a ListView that displays a simple list. I've hooked up the ItemClick event like so:

```
list.ItemClick += HandleItemClick;
```

And I try to return some result and finish the activity.

```
void HandleItemClick (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs args)
{
    var result = 42;

    // Return the data?
    Intent output = new Intent();
    output.PutExtra("meaningOfLife", output);
    SetResult(Result.Ok, output);

    Finish(); // <-- Java.Lang.StackOverflowError
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

Johan

Comment: You probably want to replace the second parameter on PutExtra method from 'output' to 'result'...

Comment: Ahh, It was to late.... Thanks! Put it as the answer so I can give you your well deserved points! :D I'll just go and feel ashamed now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to replace the second parameter on PutExtra method from 'output' to 'result'...